# Error with "Warning: opendir"

Tags: permissions

After installing and uninstalling wysiwyg I get the erorr:

```
Warning:
opendir(sites/all/modules/wysiwyg/editors,sites/all/modules/wysiwyg/editors):
The specified network name is no longer available. (code: 64) in
file_scan_directory() (line 2038 of
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\grupa2calendar\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\includes\file.inc).
Warning: opendir(sites/all/modules/wysiwyg/editors): failed to open
dir: Permission denied in file_scan_directory() (line 2038 of
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\grupa2calendar\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\includes\file.inc).
```

I tried rebuilding the permissions but no luck, how could I solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, seems that the azure server is really slow, so it took some time for the cache clearing and permission rebuilding. Did those things and after an hour the problem just went away..